# Azure static web app: staticwebapp.config.json not found using Github actions

Tags: angular, azure, github-actions, cicd, azure-static-web-app

Adding a staticwebapp.config.json always results in not found error of the config file.
I added a staticwebapp.config.json into the assets folder of my angular project, but the build alsways failes with a error saying that the staticwebapp.config.json could not be found.

My Actionfile looks like this:

```yaml
 steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          submodules: true
      - name: Build And Deploy
        id: builddeploy
        uses: Azure/static-web-apps-deploy@v1
        with:
          azure_static_web_apps_api_token: ${{ secret }}
          repo_token: ${{ secret  }} # Used for Github integrations (i.e. PR comments)
          action: "upload"
          ###### Repository/Build Configurations - These values can be configured to match your app requirements. ######
          # For more information regarding Static Web App workflow configurations, please visit: https://aka.ms/swaworkflowconfig
          app_build_command: "npm run build-prod"
          app_location: "/" # App source code path
          api_location: "" # Api source code path - optional
          output_location: "dist/myApp" # Built app content directory - optional
          config_file_location: "/asstets"
          ###### End of Repository/Build Configurations ######
```

And the assets folder is added in the angular.json:

```json
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
```

Already tried other config_file_location like "./dist/myApp", "./dist/myApp/assets", "/asstets", "./assets", but still the same error.

Building the angular app locally results into these artifacts within the dist/myApp:
[image: local build artifacts]

staticwebapp.config.json:

```json
{
  "navigationFallback": {
    "rewrite": "/index.html",
    "exclude": ["*.{css,scss,js,png,gif,ico,jpg,svg}"]
  }
}
```

The error message:

```
App Directory Location: '/' was found.
config_file_location: config file '/assets/staticwebapp.config.json' could not be found.
```

Expected behavior:
Successful build with config_file_location: "/assets"

Comment: Your `config_file_location` is set to `/asstets`. Is the spelling correct, cross check once.

Comment: If the config file is in root folder, then 
`config_file_location: .`

If the file is in `src\assets` folder, then 
`config_file_location: "src\assets"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have created an `Angular App` and added the `staticwebapp.config.json`  file.

As mentioned in the [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/configuration#file-location), the config file has to be in the Application root directory.

> The recommended location for the *staticwebapp.config.json* is in the folder set as the `app_location` in the workflow file.

- As my `app_location` is `/` -  root directory, created the config file in the root directory itself.
- Added the same configuration in `staticwebapp.config.json` which you have provided.

***My YAML file:***

```cs
   app_location: "/" 
   api_location: "" 
   output_location: "dist/angular_app"
```

If the config file is in root folder, then

```cs
   config_file_location: .
```

If the file is in `src\assets` folder, then

```cs
config_file_location: "src\assets"
```

Iam able to build and deploy successfully with both the configurations.

[image]

- If you want to place the configuration in assets folder itself, make sure you are providing the path for `config_file_location` correctly.
- Your config file is in the assets folder, but you have set the location as `/asstets`.

I have also tried by placing the config file in `src\assets' folder.

Then the `config_file_location` has to be set to `src/assets`.

***Output:***

[image]

Comment: @Harshitha The Docs also state that any sub folder is valid "However, the file may be placed in any subfolder within the folder set as the app_location".  Your answer is very good and solves the problem but do "sub folder" exclude sub sub folders?

Comment: AFAIK,the sub folder doesn't exclude sub sub folders.

Comment: I have provided the solution with both root and assets folder.